# Wifi didn't connect after ugrade kernel 3.11.0-15-generic

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

sorry but I'm from germany. My english is not good.

I have installed xubuntu 12.04.3 on my laptop. I couldn't get sound over hdmi so i upgraded the kernel to 3.11.0-15-generic. SInce this update and after i reinstalled the nvidia driver my HDMI AUdio works very well. But now my wlan has a problem. Normaly after login the wlan connects automaticaly. But now no connection. When i disable WLAN (keyboard: fn + F11) and enable again, than wlan connects without any problems. WIred is not connected.

`sudo lshw -C network

    *-network

       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface

       Produkt: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller

       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.

       Physische ID: 0

       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:06:00.0

       Logischer Name: eth0

       Version: 02

       Seriennummer: 00:90:f5:91:b3:43

       Größe: 10Mbit/s

       Kapazität: 1Gbit/s

       Breite: 64 bits

       Takt: 33MHz

       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation

       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s

       Ressourcen: irq:46 ioport:4000(Größe=256) memory:f4100000-f4100fff memory:f4000000-f400ffff memory:f4020000-f403ffff

  *-network

       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung

       Physische ID: 4

       Bus-Informationen: usb@2:5

       Logischer Name: wlan0

       Seriennummer: 00:25:d3:2d:92:26

       Fähigkeiten: ethernet physical wireless

       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8187 driverversion=3.11.0-15-generic     firmware=N/A ip=192.168.251.131 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg`

Have anyone an idea what the problem is?

Greetings

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, that you disable and then enable wireless with the key combination with Fn+F11, it sounds as if the wireless is booting up soft-blocked. Let's unblock the wireless on boot and see if it helps. Please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Right above the line 'exit 0'  add one new line:

```
rfkill unblock all
```

Proofread, save and close gedit. Now does your wireless connect on boot?

Comment: Perfect. Now it is working. Thank you very much!